# Find $a$ and $b$ that maximize the value of the integral $\int ^{b}_{a}\left( 1-x^{2}\right) dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

**Original Title:** Range that maximizes the value of the integral

Can you help me with this question?
$\int ^{b}_{a}\left( 1-x^{2}\right) dx$ dFind the constants  and  that make the maximum of the curve. (By explaining and explaining the reasons
find).

Comment: Das kann ich gar nicht verstehen.  Schreiben Sie Ihre Frage auf Englisch bitte.

Comment: I hope people are not downvoting because the question is not in English. The [FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617) is quite clear on this; the three by far most upvoted answers are all in favour of allowing questions to be posted in other languages (and then translated).

Comment: Sorunu denedin mi? Burada ödev yanıtı yok.

Comment: @joriki  I agree with you, but with one remark.  The OP could also try to use a translator like Google Translate to help with the translation.  If the OP is not confident that the translator is sufficient, then the question in the OP's language should also be there so that people who knows the language can help translate.  I encouraged many users to add their questions in their own languages.  (I didn't downvote this question, and my comment above was a joke.)

Comment: @Ridvan write your question in english please( burada turkce yazarsin sana cevab yazmazlar)

Comment: @Batominovski: Klar, ich hab den Witz verstanden ;-) And I agree with what you say about providing an automatic translation.

Comment: @haqnatural: a) I've already added an English translation of the question. b) It's not true that we won't reply if the question is written in Turkish; I've already posted an answer :-).

Comment: so sorry my fault

Comment: $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

Comment: @alapan das  i found it but i want an explanation

Answer (score 3):

The integrand is positive on $(-1,1)$ and negative outside $[-1,1]$, so the integral is maximized if it is performed over $[-1,1]$, that is, if $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

Technically speaking, the integral can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $a=-1$ and $b$ a large negative number, but I doubt that this is the intention of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For $y>x$,

$\int_{x}^{y} (1-t²) dt=(y-x)-\frac{(y³-x³)}{3}=A(x,y)$

Now, for some $x<1$, $A(x,y)$ will have maximum value for y=1.
 As, $\frac{\partial A(x,y)}{\partial y}=1-y²=0 \Rightarrow y=1$. Because for $y=-1, \frac{\partial^2 A(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=3>0$.

So, for fixed $x<1$, $A$ will be maximum for $y=$ and that value will be $A(x,1)=\frac{2}{3}+(\frac{x³}{3}-x)$.

And $A(x,1)$ will be extremum when $ \frac{\partial A(x,1)}{\partial x}=0 \Rightarrow 1-x²=0 \Rightarrow x=±1$.

And $\frac{\partial^2 A(x,1)}{\partial x^2}<0$ for $x=-1$.

So, $A(x,y)$ will be maximum when $x=a=-1$ and $y=b=1$.

Comment: thank you very much